# Quelle est la différence entre « acidique » et « acide » ?

Tags: sens, adjectifs

Est-ce que le mot « acidique » est un anglicisme ? Selon Wiktionnaire, on peut dire « [acidique](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/acidique) » pour signifier « À l’acide ». Mais je ne trouve pas ce mot dans le *Trésor de la langue française informatisé* (TLFi) ([CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/acidique)).

Si ce mot existe en « bon français », quelle est la différence entre *acidique* et *acide* ? Les phrases utilisant « acidique » dans Wiktionnaire sont

> - La première phase comprenait le traitement **acidique** de la formation pétrolifère.
> - La corrosion **acidique**.

Est-ce qu'on peut dire « le traitement **acide**... » ou « la corrosion **acide** » ?

Comment: Première fois que j'entends ce mot (et je suis natif)... Probablement un anglicisme ou un terme technique.

Answer (score 1):

Il est certain que de nombreuses personnes responsables dans diverses organisations pensent que l'on peut utiliser cet adjectif. En plus des exemples du wiktionnaire cités on trouve les exemples suivant dans les [annonces](https://fr.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=acidique&title=Sp%C3%A9cial%3ARecherche&go=Continuer).

> **Pain** 
>   le pain se fait souvent avec le seigle. Ce pain se fait avec un **levain acidique**, car le seigle ne possède pas de gluten, contrairement au blé, et les amylases
>   **Bagnoli di Sopra Friularo** 
>   vieillissement saveur : sec, plein, épicé, équilibré, assez tannique, légèrement acidique Le Bagnoli di Sopra Friularo se déguste à une température de 14 à 16 °C
>   **Oxaziridine** 
>   sont très utiles pour préparer des époxydes sensibles aux **conditions acidiques**. Ci-dessous est décrit la synthèse de la (-)-chaetominine qui utilise
>   **Extraction par sorption sur barreau magnétique** sous des conditions hors-équilibre. Lorsqu’il s’agit d’analyte de nature **acidique** ou basique, le pH de la solution joue un rôle important. Selon le pKa,

D'après les annonces le mot est utilisé dans des organisations dans le domaine de production ou d'élaboration de nourriture et dans des laboratoires où la chimie est la discipline fondamentale. On voit qu'il est utilisable pour caractériser des gouts acides de la nourriture (comme l'adjectif traditionnel). Vous devez vous rendre compte d'après les exemples qu'il n'y a pas de différence entre « acide » et « acidique ».

L'introduction du terme peut se comprendre ainsi : l'adjectif qui a servi pour caractériser l'un des deux grands groupes d'agents corrosifs, c'est à dire les bases, est « basique »; celui qui a servi pour l'autre groupe, les acides, est « acide » ; comme de plus en anglais ces adjectifs sont respectivement « basic » et « acidic » il y avait un chemin tout tracé pour rendre le vocabulaire de la chimie plus fonctionnel selon deux points de vue. Donc, c'est un néologisme qui amène quelque chose de positif. Dire qu'il existe maintenant en « bon français » est une autre histoire, disons qu'il devrait comme il le rend meilleur ; il me semble qu'il devrait remplacer l'adjectif traditionnel mais on ne sait jamais: cela dépendra de personnes comme vous qui auront eu à décider et qui auront choisi, comme il n'y a pas d'autre principe plus important à l'heure actuelle qui soit un facteur de décision dans ce domaine.

Comment: Merci pour votre réponse ! Oui, le « bon français » est une question d'appréciation. Parce que l'anglais est mon langue première, en général, je voudrais éviter d'employer des anglicismes, mais il faut considérer chaque mot individuellement.